# Splitting a Multi-Page MS Access report into individual pdf files based on a Customer ID?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking to split a multi-page access report up into individual pdf files based on a Customer ID and then saving those pdf files based on the Customer Name (or ID).

I've looked into 'printing'/'converting' the report into one massive pdf file and splitting it there, but some customer invoices span two+ pages, therefore splitting that one pdf file page-by-page doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated; if anyone needs more clarification on anything, don't hesitate to let me know.

Answer (score 4):

This can be easy with Access 2007 (see note below) or later.

Open your report using the `WhereCondition` parameter to limit the record source to a specific customer.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptFoo", acViewPreview, , "Customer_ID = 1"
```

Then use OutputTo to save it as PDF with a file name you supply.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "Spacely_Sprockets.pdf"
```

Close the report afterward.

```
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptFoo"
```

You could create a procedure which opens a recordset for `Customer_ID` and `Customer_Name` data, then use those 3 commands with values from each row.

If your Access version is older than 2007, you'll have to tell us about the method you're using to create PDF files.

Note: For Access 2007, Office Service Pack 2 provides [Built-in Save As PDF/XPS support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953195).

Answer (score 2):

PDF printing is available with MS Access 2010, for 2007, you can install an add-on from Microsoft : [Print, share, and protect files in the PDF and XPS file formats](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/print-share-and-protect-files-in-the-pdf-and-xps-file-formats-HA010167527.aspx#_Toc290894468)

For versions prior to 2007, you can use :

- Stephen LeBan's [ReportToPDF](http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm) consists of just two DLLs but only works with MS Access
- [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) is free and easy to use.
- [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/) is also free and can be fully automated with VBA (though I have not used it lately, I believe this feature is still available)
- Any number of paid-for PDF creators.

The WHERE argument for OpenReport has been available since the [2003 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210291%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (also [OpenReport 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx))

To print a report for all customers for version 2003, 2007 and 2010, you can loop through the relevant file and

```
Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT CustimerID FROM Invoices")

   Do While Not rs.EOF
      ''expression.OpenReport(ReportName, View, FilterName, 
      ''      WhereCondition, WindowMode) -- 2010 has OpenArgs

      DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoices",<..>,,"CustomerID=" & rs!CustomerID
      ''OutputTo or other relevant code

      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
```

Getting a PDF then depends on your version and the tools you have installed. If you are using PDFCreator or CutePDF, for example, you can use `acViewNormal` for the view. PDFCreator set up will allow you to assign a file name in advance, for CutePDF, you will have to fill in a file name. For Access 2007 and 2010, you can use `OutputTo`, as has already been mentioned, so `acViewPreview` is best.

To email a report for 2007 and 2010, you can use [SendObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214075%28v=office.12%29.aspx). For earlier versions, you will need quite a bit more code. The easiest option is probably to automate Outlook.