# Access 2010/2007 VBA email daily report to companys based on table with email addresses

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-access-2010

Basically I need to send a report each day to dealers we disburse funds to.  I have a table that has the dealer names, ID number, and their email addresses.

For each report I need to loop through this table and send an email to the corrisponding dealer by ID number.

The Dealer information:

```
SELECT DealerDetail.dealer_id, DealerDetail.dealer_name, DealerDetail.email
FROM DealerDetail;
```

The query my report uses:

```
SELECT LoanDetail.Book_Date, LoanDetail.DLR_Name, 
  LoanDetail.DLR_ID, LoanDetail.Cust_ID, LoanDetail.Amt_Fin, 
  LoanDetail.APR, LoanDetail.Buy_Rate, LoanDetail.Pmt_Amt, 
  LoanDetail.TERM, LoanDetail.Part, LoanDetail.[Flat Fee]
FROM LoanDetail
WHERE (((LoanDetail.Book_Date)=Date()-1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to loop through and create an outlook instance to send the email, shown in the code below

```
Private Function SendEmail(attachment, subject,strContactEmail,strEmailText,strCc)

Dim olLook As Object                     'Start MS Outlook
Dim olNewEmail As Object                 'New email in Outlook


Set olLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNewEmail = olLook.createitem(0)


   With olNewEmail   'Attach template
      .To = strContactEmail
      .cc = strCc
      .body = strEmailText
      .subject = subject
  .attachments.Add (attachment)
  .display
   End With
 .send


End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Assuming that outlook is installed. Also, where is the report?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to loop through the dealer table and use [SendObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214075%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to send the report:

```
Dim rs AS DAO.Recordset

   Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT email FROM DealerDetail")

   Do While Not rs.EOF
      DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "ReportName", _
           acFormatPDF, rs!Email, , , "Report", "Here is the report", True
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
```

Comment: Ok the code you provided works and sends an email of the full report to each dealer in the table.  Is there any way to filter the report so only the report detail for the indiviual dealer is sent to the email address in the Dealer Detail table (matching the DLR_ID in LoanDetail Table in the report and the Dealer_ID in the DealerDetail Table)?  Thanks again!

Comment: You can OutPut to after you have opened the report with a stutaible where argument see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498794/splitting-a-multi-page-ms-access-report-into-individual-pdf-files-based-on-a-cus/11502881#11502881

Comment: I attempted your suggestion on the link above.  I'm only getting the 1st page of the report sent to all dealers.  What might I be doing wrong?  I'd like for each page of the report to be send to the corrisponding dealer ID.