# Access: print individual page to pdf, individually named file

Tags: ms-access, pdf, vba

I'm trying to create a program/macro/VBA in access to print invoices to PDF in individual files. I want the file names to be named with the invoice number as well. But I'm new to Access coding, although I can write code in VBA so I don't know what command I need to do the things above. Here's my plan:

1. Create a report for the invoices so that it will create 1 invoice on 1 page.
2. Loop through the table/query (while loop with EOF, for loop with table size)
3. As long as there's the next record, create a report page for it.
4. Only print the current page and name it with the corresponding invoice number.
5. Move on

I know access has a tool to create macro to print to PDF, but it prints everything and doesn't work on individual pages. That's why I think I should use loop. So I want to know:

-Is there a better way to do this?

-If I have to do it this way, then what commands do I need to use.

-I've seen people use these codes:

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [GROUP] FROM [REPORT]", dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Can you explain what these mean?

Also, I do this at work so I can't install programs. I use Access 2010

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11502881/2548

Comment: When I removed the quotation marks, access returns the error "expected: =" right after "windowMode) " It's not a logic error so I'm sure something is missing in that code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The line you have removed the quote from is a comment to show the arguments, do not remove the quotes.

Comment: ok, I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For such a problem, I would work with the filtering capabilities of your report...
- Build a query that would prepare all data you need for your invoices (In my case INVOICE)
- Build a report that would print all invoices, based on you query INVOICE
- Use the "Where condition" when opening the report to filter on 1 invoice only
For example, the following code does a .pdf per invoice, name of pdf is ID of invoice. I used INVOICE_ID As the unique ID of the invoice

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub startInvoice_Click()

    Dim myrs As Recordset
    Dim myPDF, myStmt As String

    ' Open a record set with a list of invoice number to print
    myStmt = "SELECT distinct invoice_id from INVOICE"
    Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(myStmt)

    ' For each invoice, print in a .pdf
    Do Until myrs.EOF

        ' Set the output path of your PDF file invoice
        myPDF = "C:\temp\INVOICE_" & Format(myrs.Fields("INVOICE_ID"), "000000") & ".pdf"

        ' Open the report with the proper where condition
        DoCmd.OpenReport "INVOICE", acViewPreview, , "INVOICE_ID = " & myrs.Fields("invoice_id").Value

        ' Generate the output in pdf
        DoCmd.OutputTo objectType:=acOutputReport, objectName:="INVOICE", outputformat:=acFormatPDF, outputfile:=myPDF, outputquality:=acExportQualityPrint

        DoCmd.Close ' Close the report
        myrs.MoveNext ' read next

    Loop

    ' some cleanup
    myrs.Close
    Set myrs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope this helps