# MS Access: Segment Report into separate output files and Output Report To PDF

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-pdf

I know the title of this thread probably doesn't appropriately describes what I am attempting...

I have a report that is grouped by customer and invoice associated to the customer.  The report, as a whole, contains multiple customers and invoices.

I would like to create code to output a PDF file for each customer as a single file, and use the invoice number to name the file.

Customer A within the report would have a PDF file for Invoice #1
Customer B within the report would have a PDF file for Invoice #2

and so on...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, what is your problem? Please make an attempt, so we can see the issues you're running into. There are enough web pages describing how to filter reports, and print reports to pdf. For pointers on how to ask good questions, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  I can output the report to a PDF easy enough...  But it would be one report containing many companies / invoices.  I need to create a routine that outputs one file for each company

Comment: Did you read the how to ask piece? Please adjust your question according to the information in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a Multi-Page MS Access report into individual pdf files based on a Customer ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498794/splitting-a-multi-page-ms-access-report-into-individual-pdf-files-based-on-a-cus)